# JSF 1.2 Error calling action method of component with id ***

Tags: java, jsf

I'm doing a tutorial which consists on how to create a Todo JSF application [link of the tutorial (7. A Todo JSF application) here.](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaServerFaces/article.html)

After running the "Todo.jsp" page on the server (tomcat), I haven't the expected list of todos created previously on the controller constructor and when I click on the "save" button I have the following ERROR:

> **Error calling action method of component with id j_id_jsp_1588810359_4:j_id_jsp_1588810359_14**
>
> Caused by:
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException - /Todo.jsp(44,3) '#{todoController.save}'
> java.lang.NullPointerException

I've already searched on the web to fix ths error but I haven't found anything helpful :(

Please ask me if I have to link any other code line.
Thank you...

**(edit)**

The first line of the stacktrace is :

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Error calling action method of component with id j_id_jsp_1588810359_4:j_id_jsp_1588810359_14
```

The URL I use is "http://localhost:8080/de.vogella.jsf.todo/faces/Todo.jsp"

and my "web.xml" is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>de.vogella.jsf.todo</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    This parameter tells MyFaces if javascript code should be allowed in
    the rendered HTML output.
    If javascript is allowed, command_link anchors will have javascript code
    that submits the corresponding form.
    If javascript is not allowed, the state saving info and nested parameters
    will be added as url parameters.
    Default is 'true'</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    If true, rendered HTML code will be formatted, so that it is 'human-readable'
    i.e. additional line separators and whitespace will be written, that do not
    influence the HTML code.
    Default is 'true'</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    If true, a javascript function will be rendered that is able to restore the
    former vertical scroll on every request. Convenient feature if you have pages
    with long lists and you do not want the browser page to always jump to the top
    if you trigger a link or button action that stays on the same page.
    Default is 'false'
</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.MyFacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: could you provide our `.jsp` and `.java` ,please.Or it is the same as in tutorial?

Comment: have you debugged your code?are you sure `form` variable is not `null` in bean?

Comment: it's the same as the tutorial actually

Comment: I don't know how to debug the code... I'll search for that now

Comment: for WIN(command line):
`set JPDA_ADDRESS=8000
set JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
bin/catalina.bat jpda start`

Comment: if you use Eclipse ,go to Run-->Debug configurations-->Remote Java Application ,create new ,specify 8000 port

Comment: What does this configuration do please?

Comment: do you use Eclipse? this configuration allows you to debug your application, in case you Tomcat is running in debug mode.In order to run it in debug mode ,execute command from command line:`set JPDA_ADDRESS=8000 set JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket bin/catalina.bat jpda start`

Comment: Yes i'm using eclipse, well I've exectued the command, and while debugging I have this error

Comment: Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.
Connection refused: connect

Comment: have you ran you tomcat in debug mode?

Comment: I think so.. how can I check that please?

Comment: you should execute 3 command from command line

Comment: `set JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket`

Comment: and finally run your Tomcat:`bin/catalina.bat jpda start`

Comment: I have not a batch file named catalina.bat in my tomcat/bin folder

Comment: the content of by tomcat/bin folder is:

Comment: Répertoire de C:\tomcat632\bin

11/07/2012  16:02    <REP>          .
11/07/2012  16:02    <REP>          ..
02/02/2011  20:04            22 226 bootstrap.jar
02/02/2011  20:04         1 157 632 tcnative-1.dll
02/02/2011  20:04            26 532 tomcat-juli.jar
02/02/2011  20:04            96 256 tomcat6.exe
02/02/2011  20:04           102 912 tomcat6w.exe

Comment: strange, it should be,it's standard batch file.Try to download other Tomcat from oficcial site, 7 version

Comment: Unfortunately, I "have" to use this version (v6)... but I can run the server from eclipse and using the tomcat6w.exe file in the tomcat/bin folder

Comment: Real time conversations are meant for chat.stackoverflow.com, not the comments. Please take your conversation there. If there's anything that belongs in the question (hint: edit your question), then please move the pertinent information to your question.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I think that I haven't enough reputation to be able to talk on the chat, am I wrong?

Comment: The line which you presented as "first line of the stacktrace" isn't the first line of the stacktrace at all. It's just the exception type and message. The stacktrace is that part of the exception with all FQN class/method names and line numbers, usually prefixed with "at". The 1st line of the stacktrace of the root cause exception (the bottommost exception in the stacktrace) gives you the exact class/method and line number where the exception was caused. All with all, I suggest to learn a bit more basic Java before diving in Java EE / JSF.

Answer (score -2):

your todocontroller is null. Did you register it as described in the Tutorial?

> 7.4. Register your managed beans

Comment: yes i had registred it as a <managed-bean> in the faces-config.xml file

Comment: any other suggestion please ?

Comment: can you paste your web.xml and the URL you use to access todo.jsp please

Comment: I don't think the problem comes from the mapping but there is by web.xml and the URL I use...

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. If this was the case, it would have thrown a different exception. OP's particular problem is just caused by a bug in `save()` method which is in turn unrelated to JSF, but more related to basic Java.

Comment: @BalusC have you any idea about how to fix the problem please?

Comment: The 1st line in the stacktrace is the line which contains the bug. The code in that line is attempting to access a reference which is actually `null`.

Comment: yes, that's what I "suspected" but I don't know why is it null?! I've carefully checked the code and haven't found any problem...